# Smart selections (between quotes) for notepad++

Tags: notepad++, selection, code

```
def "Abc the quick brown fox jumped over def"
  print "Hello World"
end
```

Suppose my cursor is somewhere between abc and def, 
how can i make notepad++ select the whole text
between the double quotes?

I'm thinking there should be an easy shortcut for this.

There's a plugin out there (https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el)
but it doesnt work with notepad++

Comment: you may try to adapt this http://sourceforge.net/p/npppythonscript/discussion/1188885/thread/4c117d91/

Answer (score 2):

This may not be simple enough for you but the Notepad++ Find/Replace (ctrl-f) function with Regular expressions enabled could do what you want.

If you search for `\"[\w ]*\"` it will select the string, including the quotes.

Comment: I had better luck with `\".*?\"` because it also captured other punctuation between the quotes, not just word characters.